# Increment row reference based on index in selection, and not same row number between sheets

Tags: excel

I have a workbook containing two sheets. Sheet 1 has values in column A for every row up to row number 2000. Sheet 2 should duplicate the values over multiple rows for each row in Sheet 1. Like this:

```
Sheet1:
a1 | 123
a2 | 456
a3 | 789
```

and for Sheet2:

```
Sheet2:
a1 | 123
a2 | 123
a3 | 456
a4 | 456
a5 | 789
a6 | 789
```

The duplication is fairly simple, where I just put a reference of the next rows to the row collecting the row value from Sheet1:

```
a2: =a1
```

However, selecting and dragging rows a1 and a2 in Sheet2 to get the corresponding formulas copied over to the next rows, the formula does not reference the correct rows in Sheet1. Something like this occurs:

```
Sheet2:
a1 | 123
a2 | 123
a3 | 789
a4 | 789
```

Where cell a3 in Sheet2 references cell a3 in Sheet1, instead of cell a2 which is the next row. I have tried several functions with index, offset etc. but none of them seem to circumvent the automatic same-row-reference between the worksheets. Any quick ideas?

Comment: If it's always just two values `=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0))`?

Comment: Yes, it's a set interval between rows, so this actually works for a quick solution! Thanks :) However, a generic approach could still be useful, just in case something messes up in the counting

Comment: You basically have to come up with a relationship between "output" rows and "input" row numbers. Not necessarily involving rounding, that just worked for your example, but could be simple arithmetic or using MOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"generic approach" imho is either one of these.. :

1. Just edit the "2" in the 1st comment ans.
2. use `ROW()` and argument for `OFFSET()`
3. 'Manually' build the reference using `INDIRECT`
4. set the 1st 2 row manually, 3rd row onward use `=IF(A2=A1,INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(row()+1)/2,TRUE),A2)` and drag downwards.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: glad it solved.. credit to @SJR too.. ( used is as 1 in the solution)